# Downcasting NSCollectionViewItem from makeItem crashes

Tags: arrays, xcode, macos

I have a custom item class

```swift
class AttachmentCell: NSCollectionViewItem {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

that I try to instantiate in a delegate as

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

        let item = collectionView
            .makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "AttachmentCell"),
                      for: indexPath) as! AttachmentCell

        return item
    }
```

Now the program crashes with the error

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSCollectionViewItem' (0x7fffa5050690) to 'Notes.AttachmentCell' (0x10000ee38).
2019-06-04 13:01:33.603441+0200 Notes[18477:37049533] Could not cast value of type 'NSCollectionViewItem' (0x7fffa5050690) to 'Notes.AttachmentCell' (0x10000ee38).
```

It was my understanding that makeItem should give me an object of the type I gave it (and I think I have seen this work before), so I have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was simply that I had put the wrong class in the nib file :-S